What is the consequence of not mentioning an in-text citation in Bibliography
I have recently submitted a paper to a reputed Wiley Journal. I have used in-text citations in the main body, with all references alphabetically arranged at the end of paper in a bibliographical section. Few hours after submitting the paper, I realized that I have not mentioned one, single in-text citation in the Bibliography, i.e. I have named the source (Author, year and page no.), in the main body, but I have not mentioned the complete name and details in the Bibliography, which is an unintentional formatting error. How will this effect my paper's review and publication prospects?

Are you doing this manually or using citation management software? I highly recommend using citation management software if you are not yet familiar with it.

A reviewer might point it out, and, either way, you get to fix it later in the publishing process.

It is unlikely that it will affect the review, and not especially likely that it will be noticed. But you will have a chance to make a correction/addition before publication.
Few papers are published exactly as first submitted (by reputable journals, anyway) and most go through one or more edit phases.
You can mention it to the editor if you like, but for now there is little to do or to worry about.

I have mentioned it to the Editor, and have also e-mailed the missing reference, along with the position where it is to placed. Would that be helpful?

Should be fine. Don’t worry.
